# Recursively determine minimum moves to all fields on gameboard

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion

I'm in the process of trying to understand recursion better, so I decided to write a program to determine the shortest paths to all fields on an N * N game board, using recursion (I know BFS would be faster here, this is just for the sake of learning):

```
void visit(int x, int y, int moves)
{
  if (x < 0 || x >= n || y < 0 || y >= n) {
    return; // out of board
  } else if (board[y][x] != -1) {
    // already visited, check if path is shorter
    if (moves < board[y][x]) board[y][x] = moves;
    return;
  } else {
    // first time visiting
    board[y][x] = moves;

    visit(x + 1, y, moves + 1); // right
    visit(x, y + 1, moves + 1); // down
    visit(x, y - 1, moves + 1); // up
    visit(x - 1, y, moves + 1); // left
  }
}
# called with visit(0, 0, 0), so it should be able to start at any field
```

However, for a 3x3 board, it yields the following board:

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
6 5 4
```

The first two rows are right, however, the last row (except the last column in the last row) is wrong. It should be:

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

Here's a 4x4 board:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
12 9 6 5
13 8 7 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else if (board[y][x] != -1) {
    // already visited, check if path is shorter
    if (moves &lt; board[y][x]) board[y][x] = moves;
    return;
}
```

Returning here is wrong. You've just lowered the score on this path—there are probably other paths in the area whose scores could be lowered:

```
void visit(int x, int y, int moves)
{
  if (x < 0 || x >= n || y < 0 || y >= n) {
    return; // out of board
  } else if (board[y][x] == -1 || moves < board[y][x]) {
    // first time visiting
    board[y][x] = moves;

    visit(x + 1, y, moves + 1);
    visit(x, y + 1, moves + 1);
    visit(x, y - 1, moves + 1);
    visit(x - 1, y, moves + 1);
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Works as expected.

Comment: you also need to make sure the calls to `visit` happen they won't if you just remove the `return` because of the `if`.

Comment: The solution was simply to `return` if the moves aren't better at the field, since then there's no reason to continue. I've added my working code to this answer, but it is awaiting "peer review".

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a depth first search which may find sub-optimal paths to some squares.

To get optimal paths, if your path is shorter you should still visit from it, even if it is already visited.

Comment: That's what I'm attempting to do in the `else if` condition.

Comment: No, your else only executes if the square hasn't been visited; if you are revisiting a square with a shorter path, you should also visit from there.

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
void visit(int x, int y, int moves)
{
  if (x < 0 || x >= n || y < 0 || y >= n) {
    return; // out of board
  } 
  else if ( board[y][x] == -1 || moves < board[y][x]) 
  {
    board[y][x] = moves;
    visit(x + 1, y, moves + 1);
    visit(x, y + 1, moves + 1);
    visit(x, y - 1, moves + 1);
    visit(x - 1, y, moves + 1);
  }
}
```

Moreover, if you initialize each element of board with (2*n-2) instead of -1, you can drop the ( board[y][x] == -1 ) condition and have just (moves < board[y][x]) in the else if part.